# How to do practice SQL statements online instead of on my computer?

Tags: database

I don't want to install 3-4 databases on my computer. I had seen a website where i could make a database on a website, store it on the website itself and run SQL queries against it. I forgot the name of that site.

Now, I am looking for a website which allows me to do all this. Can you suggest some websites that can do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Ben - that is the site whose name i forgot ! thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practice here... http://www.sql-ex.ru/

Comment: Not what i was looking for. Its also not nice. SQLFiddle is much better. Thanks though.

Comment: @READER - need the points. LOL !